# How to get all Collection Names in mongodb with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Something is wrong with my code, because I get a fatal error when I try to call to method `getCollectionNames()`.

`listCollections()` works perfectly.

This is my code.

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new MongoDB\client;
$database = $client->test;
$colections = $database->getCollectionNames();

foreach ($colections as $col) {
    var_dump($col);
}
```

...and this is the error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   MongoDB\Database::getCollectionNames() in
>   (some route) Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in (some route) on
>   line (some line)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, the `MongoDB\Database` class doesn't have a method `getCollectionNames`: https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/class/MongoDBDatabase/ Why are you looking for it when `listCollections` already works?

Comment: @deceze Alright... I see. Well I'm trying to use `getCollectionNames()` because I just need the names of every single collections. Not all the data. Just names.

Comment: It's trivial to map the returned list of collection infos to only their names…

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php

    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB("demo");
    $collections = $db->listCollections();

    foreach ($collections as $collection) {
       // ...
    }

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.listcollections.php

Comment: I tried that before, and returns me an error as well. `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Model\CollectionInfo::count()` However, I just need the collections names.

Comment: Thank you to help me out! I tried that as well and not working. same error.

Comment: try `var_dump($collections);` before the `foreach` to see how to access `collectionNames`

Comment: My question has already been solved. It's because I'm using MongoDB\Database class and doesn't have this method. docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/class/… Thanx for your help anyway.

Comment: you're welcome, yes the class doesn't have that method that's why i suggested to try `listCollections` instead, have you tried my last comment with `listCollections` and not `getCollectionNames` ?

Comment: Yes, in fact I tried it before ask on SO. I'm gonna use `listCollections()` and then `getName()`. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome :) glad you worked it out, since the question doesn't need further answers, you should mark it as resolved or accept answer or something, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try pointing the MongoDB client to the instance of Mongo running on your PC, this way:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

First, try executing the `getCollectionNames` command in the MongoDB shell, like this :

```
use dbname; // dbname is your database name
dbname.getCollectionNames();
```

> Maybe, it's possible that you're not loading the library properly in the `require()` method, so check that again. I know you're using **composer**, but just check the relative location of the folder.

Or, as pointed out above you could use `listCollections()` as well :

```
<?php

$client = new MongoClient();
$db = $client->selectDB("test");
$collections = $db->listCollections();

foreach ($collections as $collection) {
    echo " ... " . "<br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: Not working, although in the MongoDB shell works perfectly and `listCollections()` as well. Something wrong with CollectionNames method

Comment: Did you check the `require` method? Are you sure it's `require '../vendor/autoload.php';` and not `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`? Because people run the **composer** installation cmds inside their current working directory and still end up loading from "outside".

Comment: Yes. I checked that out. The point is that listCollections() works perfectly.

Comment: What version of Mongo are you using? Because [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames) clearly states that it will return an empty array for shell lower than Mongo 3.x.

Comment: It's solved. It's because I'm using MongoDB\Database class and doesn't have this method. https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/class/MongoDBDatabase/ Thanx for your help anyway.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method  :

```
 require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php' ;
 $connection = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"); 
 $DB = $connection->dbName ;

foreach ($moDB->listCollections() as $item) {
    echo $item['name'] . "\n";
}
```

> Note that the package below with this version should be installed in your project

composer.json :

```
{
"require": {
    "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.4",
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `\MongoDB\Driver\Manager`, you can use this code to list collections of MongoDB database:

```
$colls = $mongo->executeCommand("my_db_name", new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'listCollections' => 1,
    'nameOnly' => 1,
    'authorizedCollections' => 1,
]);

$colls->setTypeMap(array(
    'array' => 'array',
    'document' => 'array',
    'root' => 'array'
));

foreach ($colls as $c)
    echo($c['name']);
```

To check if collection exists, you can

```
$exists = in_array("my_collection_name", $colls);
```